# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_role'

Tags: discord.py, attributeerror

I'm trying to get all users with a specific role but idk how to get this specific role, I searched and found `guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)`, but doesn't work ;-;

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

TOKEN    = # token
GUILD_ID = # guild id
ROLE_ID  = # role id

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', intents=discord.Intents.all())
guild = bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID)

admin_role = guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_role'`

I don't know how to resolve HELP ;-;

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `guild` is `None` because you have to wait for your bot to successfully connect to Discord's servers first. For this, you can simply listen for the `on_ready` bot event.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

TOKEN    = # token
GUILD_ID = # guild id
ROLE_ID  = # role id

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  guild = bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID)   
  admin_role = guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
  # [...] 

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Also make sure that your guild ID is correct and an Integer. Otherwise `bot.get_guild()` will still return `None`.

Comment: OMG THX, you are my hero

Comment: Glad that I could help @Ztuber45. :) Also please mark my answer as accepted if you find the time.